# Restaurant menu search Api

Tags: android, api, gdata-api, yahoo-api

I'm would like to develop an application which searches restaurants in a given location and also displays the restaurant's menu details.

Are there any existing APIs which I could reuse to develop such a restaurant search?

Comment: Oh wow, i also want to develop such great application based on ready made data or webservice. If you came to know then please let me also know.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use Yahoo local search API for this. see this link for more info..
http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the Locu API

Documentation: https://dev.locu.com/documentation/

The basic query that I used to get menu information of restaurants by location is shown below:

```
curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search -d '{  
    "api_key" : "[insert api key]",  
    "fields" : [ "name", "menus" ],  
    "venue_queries" : 
        [    
            {      
                "location" : 
                    {
                        "locality" : ["insert city name"]
                    }   
            }  
        ]
}'
```

I then used http://curl.trillworks.com to convert my query into python (with the requests module) to actually perform the data pull. I hope this helps!